# Rename list of files based off of a list and a directory of files

Tags: bash

So, I have a master file - countryCode.tsv, which goes like this,

```
01 united_states
02 canada
etc.
```

I have another list of country files, which go like this,

united_states.txt

```
Wyoming
Florida
etc.
```

canada.txt

```
some
blah
shit
etc.
```

and, I have a list of files that are named like this,

```
01_1
01_2
02_1
02_2
etc.
```

the first part of the filename belongs to the country code in the first list, and the second part belongs to the line number of the country file.

for example,

`01_02` would contain the info related to florida (united states).

now, here comes my question,

how do i rename these numerically named files to the country_state format, i.e., for example,

`01_02` becomes `united_states_florida`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service; SO is here to help with specific coding issues; you're expected to show the code you've attempted so far and the (wrong) output generated by said code ... *then* SO members can help address issues with the code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is to first read all of the countries into an associative array, then I would iterate over that array looking for '.txt' files for each country. When I find one, read each line in turn and look for a file that matches the country code and the line number from that file. If found, rename it.

Here is some sample code:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A countries                  # countries is an associative array.
while read code country; do
  if [ ${#code} -ne 0 ]; then         # Ignore blank lines.
    countries[${code}]=${country}
  fi
done < countryCodes.txt               # countryCodes.txt is STDIN for the while
                                      # loop, which is passed on to the read command.

for code in ${!countries[@]}; do      # Iterate over the array indices.
  counter=0
  country=${countries[${code}]}
  if [ -r "${country}.txt" ]; then    # In case country file does not exist.
    while read state; do
      ((counter++))
      if [ -f "${code}_${counter}" ]; then
        mv "${code}_${counter}" "${country}_${state}"
      fi
    done < "${country}.txt"
  fi
done
```